# GNURADIO: Getting stream tags to pass over more than one block?

Tags: c++, stream, tags, gnuradio

I've just been able to build and install my own signal blocks. I simply want to make a block that forwards data but adds a tag at some defined length. Then, after the data is modulated, I've developed a block that should read the tags back to me. It works when the blocks are right next to each other.

e.g. input --> B1 --> B2 --> B3 --> output

B1 adds a tag every 50 items, B2 is some modulator (BPSK in my case), and B3 is the tag reader. It never ends up printing anything unless B3 is right after B1.

What could I be doing wrong and do I have the wrong idea about stream tags?

Answer (score 2):

It is more than likely this was resolved by now. Another venue for getting answer is gnuradio-discussion mailing list.
However, just in case someone else finds this question I might add some color that, I hope, could help.

Keep in mind that GnuRadio was in its earlier incarnation in 2012. Question does not specify GR version. These days it is GR 3.8 and 3.9 and unless I'm mistaken 3.10 is in the works.

Being new in GnuRadio game myself, I did some digging around Tags since I want to use them to pass info regarding some signal parameters down along the data path. My digging/implementation was done in GR 3.9
There are 3 primary policies for tag propagation:

1. TPP_DONT - no propagation
2. TPP_ALL_TO_ALL - tags from all inputs propagate to all outputs (default)
3. TPP_ONE_TO_ONE - tags form n-th input propagated to n-th output
4. TPP_CUSTOM - (sounds like Monty Python skit about inquisition, I know) - it is same as TPP_DONT which is why I said only 3 policies. However it indicates to reader that the block will take care of it in it's own way. Therefore it is good to use it, if nothing else for documentation purposes.

I guess the GnuRadio version used at the times applied TPP_DONT Policy (if it used policies). Hence no propagation was done for you.

These days, unless you override the default TPP_ALL_TO_ALL policy you should get your tags down the data path.

EDIT: just realised it's been described probably a lot better at https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Stream_Tags#Tag_Propagation